# How to insert current date field in docx using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I cannot figure how can I insert date and time fields into a docx.
I suppose I have to use something like

```
run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.???)
```

but I don't know how.

Bellow is a SSCCE in which `insertCurrentXxxxField()` functions are not behaving as needed.

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class InsertCurrentDateAndTimeInDocxUsingApachePOI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        XWPFDocument  document  = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun       run       = paragraph.createRun();

        run.setText("Current date:");
        insertCurrentDateField(run);

        run.setText(" current time:");
        insertCurrentTimeField(run);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("CurrentDateAndTime.docx"));
        document.write(out);
    }

    private static void insertCurrentDateField(XWPFRun run){
        run.setText("${here should be the current date field DD.MM.YY}");
    }
    private static void insertCurrentTimeField(XWPFRun run){
        run.setText("${here should be the current time field HH:MM:SS}");
    }

}
```

Comment: If you add the field in with Word, and read that file back with Apache POI, then read the value, what do you see?

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't do that, and I currently don't know how can be done, it is far beyond my assignment. Anyway, I've spent  _far_ too much time till I figured how to create a decent document containing multiple tables and headers)

Comment: Btw.: `run.getCTR().addNewFldChar()` adds a form field (FORMTEXT, FORMDROPDOWN, FORMCHECKBOX, ...)

Comment: Thank you Axel. The main problem for me was to find this kind of information (also for the explanation you gave me in your answer).  I'm sure it has to be somewhere, but I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Word` the fields are in the `Paragraph`, not in the `Run`. But the `Run` must be closed before the field and a new `Run` must be opened after the field.

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class InsertCurrentDateAndTimeInDocxUsingApachePOI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        XWPFDocument  document  = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun       run       = paragraph.createRun();

        run.setText("Current date:");
        insertCurrentDateField(paragraph);

        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText(" current time:");
        insertCurrentTimeField(paragraph);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("CurrentDateAndTime.docx"));
        document.write(out);
    }

    private static void insertCurrentDateField(XWPFParagraph paragraph){
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun(); 
        paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("DATE \\@ \"yyyy-MM-dd\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
    }
    private static void insertCurrentTimeField(XWPFParagraph paragraph){
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("TIME \\@ \"HH:mm:ss\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this perfect answer, and for the explanation also. Of course, for my SSCCE to work as was initially stated, small changes have to made in main().

Answer (score 0):

You could use **java.util.Calendar** and **java.text.DateFormat** to get current date and time.

**Sample code:**

```
    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("DD.MM.YY HH:mm:ss");
    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("DD.MM.YY");
    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    String currDateTime = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()); 
    String currDate = dateFormat1.format(cal.getTime()); 
    String currTime = dateFormat2.format(cal.getTime()); 

    System.out.println(currDateTime);// e.g. 28.01.16 15:36:27
    System.out.println(currDate);// e.g. 28.01.16
    System.out.println(currTime);// e.g. 15:36:27
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but it does not do exactly what I want, I think I was not enough specific in may question:  I need to see the "current" date and time when the document is opened / printed, not when is created.